# Text bacground is not transparent when printing richtextbox with water mark

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I want to print richtextbox content with a background image (watermark). I have the following code (based of work by [Martin Müller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx))

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void Print(this RichTextBox control)
        {
            RichTextBoxPrintHelper helper = new RichTextBoxPrintHelper(control);
            helper.PrintRTF();

        }
    }


public class RichTextBoxPrintHelper
    {
        RichTextBox control;
        private int m_nFirstCharOnPage;


        private const Int32 WM_USER = 0x400;
        private const Int32 EM_FORMATRANGE = WM_USER + 57;

        public RichTextBoxPrintHelper(RichTextBox controlToPrint)
        {
            control = controlToPrint;
        }

        public void PrintRTF()
        {
            PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();


            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =
            new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);


            printDocument.BeginPrint += new PrintEventHandler(this.printDocument_BeginPrint);
            printDocument.EndPrint += new PrintEventHandler(this.printDocument_EndPrint);
            printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDocument_PrintPage);

            printDocument.Print();

        }

        private void printDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            m_nFirstCharOnPage = 0;
        }

        private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int DocumentWidth = (int)(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - 0.5);
            int DocumentHeight = (int)(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - 0.5);

            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("bg.jpeg");
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, DocumentWidth, DocumentHeight), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            m_nFirstCharOnPage = FormatRange(false,
                e,
                m_nFirstCharOnPage,
                control.TextLength);

            // check if there are more pages to print
            if (m_nFirstCharOnPage < control.TextLength)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
        }

        private void printDocument_EndPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            FormatRangeDone();
        }

        public int FormatRange(bool measureOnly, PrintPageEventArgs e, int charFrom, int charTo)
        {
            // Specify which characters to print
            STRUCT_CHARRANGE cr;
            cr.cpMin = charFrom;
            cr.cpMax = charTo;

            // Specify the area inside page margins
            STRUCT_RECT rc;

            rc.top = HundredthInchToTwips(10);
            rc.bottom = HundredthInchToTwips((int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - 20);
            rc.left = HundredthInchToTwips(20);
            rc.right = HundredthInchToTwips((int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - 10);

            // Specify the page area
            STRUCT_RECT rcPage;
            rcPage.top = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Top);
            rcPage.bottom = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Bottom);
            rcPage.left = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Left);
            rcPage.right = HundredthInchToTwips(e.PageBounds.Right);

            // Get device context of output device
            IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();

            // Fill in the FORMATRANGE struct
            STRUCT_FORMATRANGE fr;
            fr.chrg = cr;
            fr.hdc = hdc;
            fr.hdcTarget = hdc;
            fr.rc = rc;
            fr.rcPage = rcPage;

            // Non-Zero wParam means render, Zero means measure
            Int32 wParam = (measureOnly ? 0 : 1);

            // Allocate memory for the FORMATRANGE struct and
            // copy the contents of our struct to this memory
            IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(fr));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(fr, lParam, false);

            // Send the actual Win32 message
            int res = SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, wParam, lParam);



            // Free allocated memory
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lParam);

            // and release the device context
            e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

            return res;
        }



        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct STRUCT_RECT
        {
            public Int32 left;
            public Int32 top;
            public Int32 right;
            public Int32 bottom;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct STRUCT_CHARRANGE
        {
            public Int32 cpMin;
            public Int32 cpMax;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct STRUCT_FORMATRANGE
        {
            public IntPtr hdc;
            public IntPtr hdcTarget;
            public STRUCT_RECT rc;
            public STRUCT_RECT rcPage;
            public STRUCT_CHARRANGE chrg;
        }



        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private Int32 HundredthInchToTwips(int n)
        {
            return (Int32)(n * 14.4);
        }

        public void FormatRangeDone()
        {
            IntPtr lParam = new IntPtr(0);
            SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, 0, lParam);
        }


    }
```

The problem is that the text printed with white background (not transparent)

[image]

Comment: [EM_SETCHARFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat) + SCF_SELECTION => [CHARFORMAT2W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformat2w_1): `dwMask = CFM_BACKCOLOR | CFM_COLOR`, `crTextColor = [ForeColor]`, **`crBackColor = [BackColor]`**

Comment: @Jimi Sorry, but I don't understand the solution. Could you write an answer with codes instead of the comment?

Comment: What do you mean you *don't understand*? Something similar is mentioned in the article you have linked; the author defines a `STRUCT_CHARFORMAT` struct (it's [CHARFORMAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformata), though, not `CHARFORMAT2W`, you need this). This structure is used in an `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` message, to define how a selection of text (or all text) is formatted. The `dwMask` member specifies what other members of the struct are relevant. You can use it to set the selection BackColor to transparent. -- I cannot post answers for now, sorry.

Comment: Note that you *should* also build a Custom Control derived from RichTextBox, add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` in its Constructor, override `CreateParams` to set `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, add the text you want to print to this Control and use your method with it. You cannot use this transparent Control alone (even though it kind of works), because the result is sub-par (poor anti-aliasing, since there's no real composition).